# Export Data from Matlab function into the global frame and default matlab arguments

Tags: file, matlab, directory

I have two things that I would like to do with my matlab function. I have a function that will get data from a series of files. Say i have this file structure:

**Number 1:**

I would like to be able to have some selected variables in a function become globally accessible and persist after the function has completed. That is say i have the following function:

```
[] = function(directory)
    b = read(directory)
    struct c = (do some stuff with b)
    somehow globalise c
end
```

I understand that you can have `c = function(directory)` and then pass a variable however i would not like to o this, i would rather that the variable c just persists in the global scope. Can this be done?

**Number 2:**

Is it possible for a matlab function to have default arguments. Lets take the function from above. What I want to do is to have the directory default as the current directory. For example if the following data structure exists:

```
 MatlabMainFolder
    -> MatlabFunctions
    -> Data
```

The user should be able to run `function` in Data and it will use the Data directory.But should also be able to do `function('../Data')` from the MatlabFunctions directy for the same effect. Is this possible?

Comment: Does someone want to add the answer using `assignin` which is a matlab function to do this? I will mark that answer correct, if you also add information from the answer already here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

I think the following should make a variable globally accessible from within the function:

```
[] = function(directory)
    b = read(directory)
    global c;           <------
    struct tmp = (do some stuff with b)
    c = tmp;            <------
end
```

Then, add `global c` in all other files where you want `c` to be available, before using it. I would recommend just using `c = function...` if at all possible, though.

As suggested by @Ben, `assignin` can also be used to assign a variable into a different workspace. That way, from a function, any variable can be assigned in the `'base'` workspace, which is the workspace accessible by all other files too. In this case:

```
assignin('base','c',c)
```

will create a variable `c` in the base workspace, with the same value as `c` in the function file. (Add this line at the end of the function).

Second:

You could do something like this:

```
function(path)
    if nargin<1
         path = '../Data';
    end

    % do things with path
end
```

This way, if `function` is called without inputs, the default path `../Data` will be used, otherwise, the path given as input will be used. `nargin` will be equal to the number of arguments that were given as input.

Answer (score 1):

To 1) globals as well as asignin are often frowned upon. You could also use `persistent`

Pseudocode snippet:

```
function out=fun((directory)
persistent out
if isempty(out) 
   fill out

return out;
```

Or even handle objects in case you feel like going modern ;)

To 2): Read about `doc InputParser` - it's more work than in many other languages - but it's possible.